# Migrate Sequelize migrations to TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, typeorm

I'm rewriting a Node.js from vanila JS to Nest.js. Sequelize was used as ORM and we decided to start using TypeORM as it's more type safe. I checked the documentation for TypeORM and it seems pretty clear, except the part that concerns converting migrations.

I can convert the existing migration files to follow TypeORM syntax and it would be OK, but how will TypeORM know which migrations to run? I know that I could specify the migration table name and use the same as Sequelize (`SequelizeMeta`), but not sure if that would be the right way. Any ideas?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What do you mean by `but how will TypeORM know which migrations to run?`?  Do you mean how to configure TypeORM to run migrations?

Comment: What I mean is that I already have a bunch of migrations written for Sequelize, that are stored in a table called SequelizeMeta. If I just convert the Sequelize migrations to use TypeORM interfaces, TypeORM will probably run all the migrations all over again on the production DB, what might create some issues. I'd like that TypeORM continues running the migrations from where Sequelize stopped

Answer (score 0):

you have to to give the connection option for the db and the migration folder location
check the link below: https://typeorm.io/migrations#generating-migrations

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32113150)

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with the same problem and my solution was not to use the sequelize-generated database with the new Nest.js app. While re-writing the application in nest.js, we created entities with the same structure as the old app, and generated migrations using typeorm, and finally ran the migrations on a new database resulting in a new database with the same structure as the old one but with no data. Then after running the migrations, we just transferred data from the old database (managed by sequelize) to the new database by running queries manually. In our case it took less effort than re-using the old database with TypeORM.